# 415 Error when using POST in Java REST web services using poster extension

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, jar

I am passing JSON data like

```
{
    "empname" : "seo"
}
```

to the **POST** url but it returns 415 error i.e **Unsupported media type**
After troubleshooting I found out that the **content-type** should be **"application/json"** in poster extension and I tried the same but didn't worked.
Below is my code for service

```
package webService;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import dao.Database;
import dao.Project;
import dto.FeedObjects;
import model.ProjectManager;


@Path("/WebService")
public class FeedService 
{
    @GET
    @Path("/GetFeeds")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String feed()
    {
    String feeds = null;
    try
    {
    ArrayList<FeedObjects> feedData = null;
    ProjectManager projectManager= new ProjectManager();
    feedData = projectManager.GetFeeds();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(feedData));
    feeds = gson.toJson(feedData);
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
    System.out.println("Exception Error"); //Console 
    }
    return feeds;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/insert/{empname}/{empsalary}")

    public String insertEmpName(@PathParam("empname") String empname,@PathParam("empsalary") String empsalary) {

        String result = "Employee Insertion Failed!!!!";
        try {

            Database database = new Database();
            Connection connection = database.Get_Connection();

            Project n = new Project();
            boolean b = n.insertEmpName(connection, empname,empsalary);

            if (b == true) {
                result = "Employee Added SuccessFully!!!!";

            } else {
                result = "Employee Already Exists!!!";
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return result;

    }

    @POST
    @Path("/justTesting")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response myresponse(FeedObjects fb)
    {
        System.out.println("Name is "+fb.getEmpname());
        return Response.status(201).entity("Tested !!").build();

    }


}
```

and here is my class with setters and getters of variables that I am passing as an parameter to the above method and calling by using its object i.e **fb**

```
package dto;

public class FeedObjects
{

private String empname;
private String empsalary;
public FeedObjects() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public String getEmpname() {
    return empname;
}
public void setEmpname(String empname) {
    this.empname = empname;
}
public String getEmpsalary() {
    return empsalary;
}
public void setEmpsalary(String empsalary) {
    this.empsalary = empsalary;
}

}
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>FirstProject</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.ServletAdaptor
            </servlet-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
  <param-value>webService</param-value>
</init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/REST/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Libraries included are as below:

- asm-3.1.jar
- gson-2.2.1.jar
- jersey-client-1.0.3.jar
- jersey-core-1.0.3.jar
- jersey-server-1.0.3.jar
- joda-time-2.0.jar
- jsr311-api-1.0.jar
- mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar

So please help me to solve the error . I am a newbie to the Java REST web services but I am trying very hard to solve this .

Comment: you are mistaking between path param and form param. Can you please share the url u tried

Comment: http://<Your IP>:<Port No>/WebService/insert/seo/50000

Comment: Yeah thats for inserting the record when you have minimum fields but suppose you have more than 30 fields to be inserted ,the url doesnt allow to insert ,so see the third part i.e POST one with the path "justTesting" .Here i want to send data in form of JSON to test the url so that it can be used by my application later on. I hope i am clear

Comment: Send it as form param.. And use @FormParam in your method

Comment: how can i use that ? can you post some example or link ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem of sending data in the form of JSON to the POST url by adding `genson`library to my project jars. It provides methods to serialize Java objects to JSON and deserialize JSON streams to Java objects. It is a json<>java streaming and databinding api. It integrates well with jersey. Here is the [Link](http://owlike.github.io/genson/)
Thank you Stackoverflow and Lathy for helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Siddhesh Kalgaonkar,

[Check this out](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-formparam-example/)

Comment: Looks pretty . Thanks @Lathy but do you have any solution using JSON . because in this solution i need to pass 30 variables for 30 fields .

Comment: I don't have the code right now.. but u can use Jackson to parse the json to java object.

Comment: i have tried [this link] (http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/) but in vain :(

Comment: 415 : Unsupported Media Type

Comment: In the example, the author used REST client to send the json(as a String). Did you do the same?

Comment: yes by using poster one of the REST client in firefox browser .

Comment: I had one doubt that when using @formparam way if i want to insert the record into database then i should write code inside that public response methodname() ?

Comment: when tried with json it gives this error :SEVERE: A message body reader for Java type, class dto.FeedObjects, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found

Comment: What is tat dto.FeedObjects

Comment: The class of setters getters .Btw i solved my problem lathy sir :)